# macros is not working in excel 2007 always getting error can't find project or library

Tags: vba, excel, macros, solver

can anyone please explain the below code of vba as I'm new

```
SolverOk SetCell:="Profit_test_prem!$q$7", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0.02", _
    ByChange:="Profit_test_prem!$b$15"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
Worksheets("Profit_test_prem").Calculate
```

Comment: Exlpaination: Defines a basic Solver model. Equivalent to clicking Solver in the Data | Analysis group and then specifying options in the Solver Parameters dialog box.

Comment: Can you please explain what does "Profit_test_prem!$q$7" this means

Comment: That is the field in the solver that Excel is allowed to change in order to try and solve the equation.

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that you are missing a reference that you need to add. You have most likely copied the code from a website or another workbook. Check with the source of your code what references are needed to get it to work.

You can then add them by going to the `VBE > Tools > References` and checking the one you need.

Given your code sample, I would guess that you may need to **add the Solver Add-in** (and thus the solver reference to the solver library). This you can do by simply activating the Add-In. This you would do under the `Developer Tab > Add-In > Solver`

Comment: Yes, when I'm going vbe>tools>reference I'm getting missing:solver.xlam in the reference box but under Developer Tab I'm not getting Add-In

Comment: Ok. Then then simply activating the Solver Add-in should resolve your problem with the missing reference.

Comment: Thanks  rohrl77 I've added solver Add-in from file>excel option then move to Add-ins tab I found the required one

Comment: Your welcome! If this is the answer then you can marke it as such, so that others don't need to review the question.